# linux terminal execute echo function

Tags: linux, bash

when I read the book *linux shell scripting cookbook*
they say when you wanna print `!`,you shouldn't put it in double quote，or you can add `\` before `!` to escape it.
e.g.

1. `$echo "Hello,world!"`
2. bash: !:event not found error
3. `$echo "Hello,world\\!"`
4. Hello,world!

but in my situation(ubuntu14.04), I get the answer like that:

1. `$echo "Hello,world!"`
2. Hello,world!
3. `$echo "Hello,world\\!"`
4. Hello,world\!

So, why in my machine can't get the same answer?

Why the escape symbol `\` was printed as a normal symbol?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're typing interactively to the shell, `!` has special meaning, it's the [history expansion character](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction). To prevent this special meaning, you need to put it in single quotes or escape it.

```
echo 'Hello, world!'
echo "Hello, world\!'
```

The reason it's not happening on Ubuntu may be because it's running a newer version of `bash`, which is apparently more selective about when history expansion occurs. It seems to require `!` to be followed by alphanumerics, not punctuation.

You don't need to do this in scripts, because history is not normally enabled there. It's just for interactive shells.

Comment: History expansions happens only when there is some non-space text on RHS of `!`

Comment: @anubhava doublequotes are non-space text.

Comment: Not sure because `echo "Hello,world!"` prints `Hello,world!` for me but `echo "Hello,world!hello"` says `-bash: !hello: event not found`

Comment: @anubhava Maybe it's a bash version issue. I get the same error as the OP when I use 4.2.37 and 3.2.48.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation I linked to that indicates why `!"` shouldn't be an event designator.

Comment: Hmm probably it is due to BASH versions. I have `4.3.33(1)-release` where history expansion doesn't happen for `"Hello,world!"`. But on `3.2.57(1)-release` I get history expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script called file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file.sh: a sample shell script to demonstrate the concept of Bash    shell functions
# define usage function
usage(){
   echo "Usage: $0 filename"
   exit 1
}

# define is_file_exits function 
# $f -> store argument passed to the script
is_file_exits(){
    local f="$1"
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && return 0 || return 1
}
# invoke  usage
# call usage() function if filename not supplied
[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && usage

# Invoke is_file_exits
if ( is_file_exits "$1" )
   then
    echo "File found"
 else
     echo "File not found"
fi
```

**Run it as follows**:

```
chmod +x file.sh
./file.sh
./file.sh /etc/resolv.conf
```